# Почему строка разбивается при передаче по сокету?

Tags: c++, сокет

Есть задача написать приложение (клиент-сервер) для передачи бинарных файлов.
Написал следующую реализацию:

Client

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#define IP "127.0.0.1"
#define PORT 27015
#define BUFSIZE 4096

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")


void sendFile(SOCKET& client_socket, char* buf, char* filepath);


int main()
{
    WSADATA d;
    int result;
    result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &d);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error WSAStartup: " << result << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET clientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "Error socket(): " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    sockaddr_in clientService;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);
    clientService.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    result = connect(
                clientSocket,
                reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&clientService),
                sizeof(clientService)
            );
    if (result != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Connection error: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    const int N = 100;
    char buf[BUFSIZE], filepath[N];
    int r;
    do
    {
        std::cin.getline(filepath, N);
        sendFile(clientSocket, buf, filepath);

        if (r > 0)
            std::cout << "Receive: " << buf << "\n";
        else if (r == 0)
            std::cout << "Connection lost\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Recv error: " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
    } while (r > 0);

    closesocket(clientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}

void sendFile(SOCKET& clientSocket, char* buf, char* filepath)
{
    try {
        FILE *f;
        f = fopen(filepath, "rb");
    
        int readed;
    
        if (f != 0)
        {
            while((readed = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), f)) != 0)
            {
                send(clientSocket, (char*)buf, readed, 0);
            }
        }
    } catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "File is not exist\n";
    }
}
```

Server

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>

#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 4096

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    int iResult;
    WSAData d;

    // Данные для сокета
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &d);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error at WSAStartup: " << iResult;
        return 1;
    }

    struct addrinfo *result = nullptr, hints;
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "getaddrinfo error: " << iResult;
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Creating socket
    SOCKET listenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    listenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (listenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "Error at socket(): " << WSAGetLastError();
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    iResult = bind(listenSocket, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Error at bind(): " << WSAGetLastError();
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (listen(listenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Listen error: " << WSAGetLastError();
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    ClientSocket = accept(listenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "Accept failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError();
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // data trade
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iSendResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    
    do
    {
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuflen), 0);
        try 
        {
            FILE *f = fopen("output.txt", "wb");
            fwrite(recvbuf, 1, iResult, f);
        } catch (...)
        {
            std::cout << "Error at file writing...\n";
        }
        if (iResult > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Recv: " << recvbuf << "\n";

            iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                std::cout << "Send failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError();
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            std::cout << "Connection closed...\n";
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Recv error: " <<WSAGetLastError();
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            return 1;
        }
    } while(iResult > 0);
}
```

Client должен ввести путь до файла, который нужно передать. В этой же директории у меня имеется файл Hello.txt, в котором содержится "Hello, world". При передаче данного файла, сервер получает данные следующим образом:

> Recv: Hell
>
> Recv: o, w
>
> Recv: orld

И записывает orld в файл. С чем это связано?

Comment: Видимо с тем, что уже записанное на предыдущем шаге стирается при открытии файла на запись. Дописывайте в конец файла. Кроме того, блоки try catch совершенно бессмысленны, вместо них должна быть полноценная обработка ошибок.

Answer (score -1):

Как написал user7860670, видимо с тем, что уже записанное на предыдущем шаге стирается при открытии файла на запись. Дописывайте в конец файла. Кроме того, блоки try catch совершенно бессмысленны, вместо них должна быть полноценная обработка ошибок.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik А что с остальными 13 ответами этого пользователя и 15 другого, в них тоже будем вставлять указание авторства?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat если кто-то хочет этим заняться, то да.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik По хорошему, это должны делать не мы, а jokerbot. Не делая этого он нарушает лицензию.